# Why so many `scsi 4:0:0:0: CDB: Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00` in my message log?

Tags: linux, scsi

My os is debian8.
 cat  /var/lgo/messages

```
Jul 23 16:56:27 hwy kernel: [  117.736167] scsi 4:0:0:0: CDB:
Jul 23 16:56:27 hwy kernel: [  117.736168] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
```

so many

```
Jul 23 16:56:28 hwy kernel: [  118.735320] scsi 4:0:0:0: CDB:
Jul 23 16:56:28 hwy kernel: [  118.735321] Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00
```

repeat for about 50 times.
What is the matter with my pc?

Answer (score 1):

`Inquiry: 12 00 00 00 24 00` is a SCSI status query; most commonly generated by a SMART inquiry, but also from a variety of other things (lots of cases can trigger probing the disk in early boot, and your system was only up for ~118 seconds when those log entries happened).

If the device in question (whatever is at `4:0:0:0`, you didn't attach any `lsscsi` output) does not support the query or was failing in certain ways, you'd get the CDB error above.